# Django Rest Framework PUT request to user model endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update my user model by adding a profile picture. I'm stuck on the fact that DRF requires a lookup for PUT requests. But the client doesn't know the user pk they just have a login token. The user would normally be obtained in a view using `request.user`

views.py:

```
class UploadViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ImageUploadSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='testuploads/', null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ImageUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = (
                'profile_image',
                )
```

Posting give the following

```
"detail": "Method \"PUT\" not allowed.",
```

Which is caused by the fact that there is no individual resource identifier in the URL. Of course, the resource (a user) could be obtained from the request because it is an authenticated request.

How can I update the user model using DRF?

**Update**
urls.py

```
router.register(r'upload', views.UploadViewset)
```

I'm posting to endpoin upload/

Comment: What is the URL that you are attempting to do this request?

Comment: Probably you are using the wrong url.

Comment: I've updated the question with urls.py and the endpoint but I find the comment weird of course it's the wrong url as I said in the question Django expects a pk in the url when doing put and I don't have a pk therefore the URL is wrong my question is how to make this work with the URL I have so I don't understand the comment